# Understand this specific use of kwargs args in a Decorator

Tags: python, decorator, args, keyword-argument

This is part of a random walk simulation in python.

Can anyone explain why "length" at the decorator is defined as:

```
length=kwargs["n"] if "n" in kwargs else args[-1]
```

Specifically:

First, I believe that the decorator print_info(func) has to return the parameter "n" used at the random_generator(n) and walk_generator(num_steps, n) functions. Is that correct?

Second, I don't understand why we are using the "dictionary" type(**kwargs). At this case, isn't (5,2) a tuple for the walk_generator function?

Third, if using **kwargs is necessary, please explain me the line (how "length" is defined) above.

Thank you:)

```
import random

def print_info(func):

    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):

        length=kwargs["n"] if "n" in kwargs else args[-1]
        print("iterator (length=%d) object is created."%length)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func


@print_info
def random_generator(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield -2*random.randint(0,1)+1

@print_info
def walk_generator(num_steps, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield random_generator(num_steps)


if __name__=="__main__":
    walk_gen=walk_generator(5,2)
    for rand_gen in walk_gen:
        print("new random walk begins")
        position=0
        for step in rand_gen:
            position+=step
            print("\t position: %d (%d)"%(position, step))
```

Comment: The `length` variable is set to the `n=` keyword parameter if it is specified (it isn't, in any of the code you posted), or the final positional parameter otherwise.  This decorator only makes sense if applied to functions whose last parameter is named `n`, and handles either possible way of giving that parameter.

Comment: `**kwargs` is always an empty dictionary throughout the code you posted - none of the function calls use named parameters, only positional ones.  `walk_generator(num_steps=5, n=2)` would be an equivalent call using named parameters.

Comment: OK, thanks. But just one more question... Then if kwargs is an empty dictionary, how can we use the expression ' kwargs["n"] '? Doesn't it mean that kwargs has a value with key "n"?

Comment: It's a conditional expresion - `kwargs["n"]` is only evaluated if `"n" in kwargs` is true.